# .htaccess RedirectMatch exclude index.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have in .htaccess a redirect that should transform the url with `.html` in without extension which works great.

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
```

I want to exclude from the rule if the filename it's named `index.html` how do I do that?

What I tried was

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/]+)/(?!index|[^/]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
```

But now it isn't working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in your rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/(?!index)([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/
```

Your attempts at negative lookahead doesn't seem to be correct because of `|` in expression.